# How to get the default filter name for an unregistered DirectShow filter

Tags: directshow

I'm loading some unregistered DirectShow filters manually from a DLL by CLSID and I'd like to find out the name of the filter (as it appears in GraphEdit).

I've tried using the `IBaseFilter:QueryFilterInfo` method but that only appears to work when the filter is part of a graph and even then, it returns the name that was given to the filter when the filter was added to the graph.

I'm looking for the *default* name that the filter would have when an instance of it is added to a graph in GraphEdit. Is it possible to get that, and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter graph assigns unique name to the filter when filter is joining the graph. The name can be suggested by filter adder, then in case of collision filter graph might append a number as a suffix. When no name is given by the adder, filter graph takes "default" name from `QueryFilterInfo` or from filter registration information, where friendly name was also a part of registration.

The registration names are managed by [Filter Mapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375788%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and accessible there programmatically. Then in turn it keeps the information in registry under category keys, esp. `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{083863F1-70DE-11D0-BD40-00A0C911CE86}\Instance` key.

Comment: So unless the filter is registered the friendly name will not be available (via Filter Mapper), correct? (as I mentioned, I checked the QueryFilterInfo and it's not returning anything)

Comment: I don't remember this behavior documented, so it's off the top of my head. The name of the filters is only a troubleshooting/development helper, so it's fine if it is empty. I suppose graph will use name, if any, returned by filter in this method as default name. However standard implementation does not do it. So you will find most unregistered filters added with names like "0002".

Comment: Yes, it's not mandatory and *most* (all filters I have) don't implement it. So it's pretty useless. I've given up on this and have since moved to a different API surface which allows the user to provide a name for the filter when adding a filter. Thanks!